# 'this is undefined' when requiring Tween.js with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, tween.js

I am using Webpack to compile all my JS into one file. The main file has this line in it:

```
import Tween from 'tween.js'
```

When I compile my file and open the HTML file that includes the result JS file in my browser, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: this is undefined
```

and the browser console points at these lines of code:

```
// Include a performance.now polyfill
  (function () {
      // In node.js, use process.hrtime.
      if (this.window === undefined && this.process !== undefined) { // it points to this line of code
          TWEEN.now = function () {
              var time = process.hrtime();

              // Convert [seconds, microseconds] to milliseconds.
              return time[0] * 1000 + time[1] / 1000;
          };
      }
```

I'm pretty sure that this `import` line cause if I comment out everything else, this error is still thrown, and if I comment out only this line, everything is working.

If I include the script directly into my HTML file, everything is okay, so I guess that's the Webpack issue.

Here is my Webpack config:

```
{
  name: 'all scripts',
  entry: {
    'main': ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, 'clientside', 'client.js')],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module:
  {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { presets:['es2015', 'stage-0'] }
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `.babelrc` file created ? If not try to create `.babelrc` file into project root, and then put this into `{"presets": ["es2015","stage-0"]}` and then remove query object from webpack config.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right import. As I checked the src file in github, it seems like the module exports TWEEN. Can you try to import TWEEN

Comment: @CagriYardimci I tried both TWEEN and Tween, both of them are throwing this error. Also I tried using `require` instead of `import`, still the same

Comment: @BelminBedak I have the `.babelrc` file in my root. I've tried deleting query from my config, still not working.